# Multiple lists in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

Can anyone suggest what is wrong with this xaml?

```
    <phone:PivotItem Header="Test" x:Name="TestTab">
        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="UserProducts" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProductList}">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid x:Name="ProductDetailsGrid">
                            <Button x:Name="DisplayProductDetails" Content="{Binding Id}" Tap="DisplayProductDetailsButton_OnTap"/>
                            <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="ListSelector">
                                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock" Text="Hi"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                            </phone:LongListSelector>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
        </Grid>
    </phone:PivotItem>
```

If I comment the inner LongList, it works fine and generate the buttons for each Item in ProductList. Does the inner list have to be bind as well? can I not bind it on run time?

IDEA:
What I want to achieve is following
when the user clicks on the particular button, I display the product details. so when user clicks on product a. I can at run time get details of product A and bind it to inner list.

Comment: Show your ProductList objects.

Answer (score 0):

what seems to happen is that LongListSelector is not  direct child of the PivotItem, you don't need the Grid, remove it, that was causing the problem.